# CodeBlocks message in console application

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I try to compile my C code in CodeBlocks 13.12, I get this message in console application: 
Process returned 30398249 <0x1CFD729>, and I can't input any number.
What should I do?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, i, j, x, s = 0;
    int *p;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (x));
        for (j = 0; j < x / 2; j++) {
            if (x % (j + 1) == 0) p[j] = 1;
            else p[j] = 0;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < x / 2; j++)
            if (p[j]) s += (1 + j);
        printf("%d\n", s);
        s = 0;
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a good place to start.

Comment: please give the code you tried to run.

Comment: it's running well...no error occurred...

Comment: @ Khairul Basar do you have codeblocks?

Comment: i compiled using codeblocks 13.12  @Ditto4

Comment: In Build  log:  Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))

Comment: no error here...
input:
5
1 2 3 4 5
output:
0 1 1 3 1

Comment: Correct...Can you write which c compiler you use? I use mingw32-gcc.exe

Comment: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26
download codeblocks 13.12 mingw-setup.exe

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with your compiler/environment, not the code given.

Comment: @Drew McGowen any suggeestions? I think that this problem comes when I used malloc without free earlier today...

Comment: My antivirus blocked codeblocks. Problem is solved now. Thanks everyone!